# For cycle & MYSQL multiplicates variable value on $i var

Tags: php, mysql

I´m trying to create vars $cdn_1 to $cdn_30 (days of the month) and assign them a value with a for cycle on php & mysql.
The value that the var gets is based on a COUNT() type mysql query. The problem here is that for example the var $cdn_6 value should be 4 but the script repeats the value the number of times the value is.
When I print $cdn_6 the value should be 4, and the output is 4444 and the same happens if the retrieved value of mysql increases, if it should be 5 it actually displays 55555. I really don't know why is this happening. I would really appreciate your help. Thanks!

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++) {
  $conalyfor=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$db);
  $queryalyfor = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `".$table_projects."` WHERE `day_id` = '".$i."' ";
  $resultalyfor = mysqli_query($conalyfor, $queryalyfor);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultalyfor)) {

  $amount_day= $row["COUNT(*)"];

  };
  mysqli_close($conalyfor);

  $string = 'cnd_'.$i;
  extract(array($string => $string));
  $varrf = "cnd_".$i;
  $$varrf = $amount_day;
  $v2 = "cnd_".$i;

};

echo $cnd_6;
```

Comment: Why not just create an array of values instead of using variable variable names? You'll run into a lot of confusion that way. You can also reduce the number of database calls by dropping the WHERE and using `GROUP BY day_id`

Comment: Hey @anyber! Thanks for your reply. I didn't understand you completely. Could you please post an answer with the code you're proposing?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: It's unclear why the table name is dynamic, but if this is because each client has their own table, that's a pretty big fault in relational database design and can lead to all kinds of messy problems.

Comment: It is also a terrible idea to open a new connection for each iteration of the loop. This could cause some serious performance issues. Make sure that you have this line before `mysqli_connect`: `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this a lot easier by first creating an empty array, then using 1 query to get all of the results grouped by `day_id`:

```
$days = array_fill_keys(range(1,31), 0); // Creates an empty array with keys 1-31

$conalyfor=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$db);
$queryalyfor = "SELECT day_id, COUNT(*) as total FROM `".$table_projects."` GROUP BY `day_id` ";
$resultalyfor = mysqli_query($conalyfor, $queryalyfor);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultalyfor)) {

    $days[$row['day_id']] = $row['total'];

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable variables are not suitable for this task. You could simply execute a single query as aynber suggested and put the values into an array with the day number as key. You can then access the values from the array using the key.

```
$results = $conalyfor->query('SELECT day_id, COUNT(*) FROM `'.$table_projects.'` GROUP BY day_id');
$days = [];
foreach($results as $row){
    $days[$row['day_id']] = $row['COUNT(*)'];
}

echo 'The count for day 6 is '.$days[6];
```